# Grep only until certain symbol

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I try to grep some string and want grep to stop at a '+' symbol. The searched string could be "foo" or "foo+bar". Grep treats all findings no matter what comes after foo and the -w option seems recognizing the '+' as whole word also. So I want to grep all files that include matches with 'foo' but not handle matches like 'foo+bar'. The command should be stored in a varaible like this

```
COUNT="$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.sh' | xargs grep -w -o -m 1 "foo" | wc -l)"
```

So how does this var has to be modified to only find the foo entries in the files but not foo+bar.

EDIT:
Finally I have the solution for my case. Maybe I did not describe clearly enough what I needed but the trick was to add a ^ at beginning and a $ at the end of the searched string.
So my files in the folder that could contain something like
text=foo or text=foo+bar
should be filtered so when I search for text=foo grep only outputs these and not including text=foo+bar.
My code now looks like

```
COUNT="$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.sh' | xargs grep -x -o -m 1 "^text=foo$" | wc -l)"
```

And now in that case grep doesnt count findings with text=foo+bar.
Sounds as simple as it is but needed again some struggle for me to figure out :)

Answer (score 2):

#### If you want to match and count (*filenames*), then ...

You might not need `grep` at all for such task ... You can include and exclude filename patterns with `find`s `-name "..."` to include and `! -name "..."` to exclude ... You can nest as many as you need of these to match only the filenames you want e.g. like so:

```bash
find -type f -name "*foo*.sh" ! -name "*+*.sh"
```

This will output files with `.sh` extension that have `foo` and don't have `+` in their names.

So your command substitution set parameter(*Notice: ALL CAPS are used for shell's built-ins ... So use lower or mixed case for your parameters*) would be:

```bash
count=$(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*foo*.sh" ! -name "*+*.sh" | wc -l)
```

Notice `.`(*current working directory*) is `find`s default search path ... So you don't have to specify it.

#### If you want to match and count (*text inside each file*), then ...

You might not need any of that at all ... But, you'll, probably, need a more sophisticated tool other than `grep` to do exactly the rather complex task of yours ... You can use only `awk` with the shell's filename globbing like so:

```bash
awk '{for ( i=1; i <= NF; i++ ) { if ( $i !~ "+" ) { if ( $i == "foo" ) { count++ }} else { nextfile }}} END { print count }' *.sh
```

`for ( i=1; i <= NF; i++ )` will pass each single field(*"word"*) in the current line on its own to the next action where `if ( $i !~ "+" )` will check if the field **doesn't** contains the `+` character(*e.g. the field is **not** `+`, `foo+bar`, `+foo` or `foo+`*) and if true, pass it to the next action where `if ( $i == "foo" )` will check if the field is exactly `foo` and if true, increment the counter using `count++` or `else` it will exit the current file and move on to processing the next file(*passed to `awk` in the file/s argument/s*) using `nextfile` and at the `END` will print the value of the current counter(*total for all processed files*) using `print count`.

And your command substitution set parameter(*Use `printf` instead of `print` to avoid injecting a newline into the parameter*) would be:

```bash
count=$(awk '{for ( i=1; i <= NF; i++ ) { if ( $i !~ "+" ) { if ( $i == "foo" ) { count++ }} else { nextfile }}} END { printf "%d", count }' *.sh)
```

This should work fine even if you run it on thousands of files ... If, however, your files are in tens of thousands or more and you get `Argument list too long` error message, then, IMHO, you need to reconsider including such a task altogether in your script and find a different approach for achieving your goal.