# exclude files that have specific characters in name

Tags: command-line, bash, find

here is my command to find files in a specific location and with specific extensions only, it works fine. But I want to exclude files that have '_bkp' or '_backup' as a substring in their file names -

```
find /httpdocs/ -type f \( -iname \*.php -o -iname \*.html -o -iname \*.js -o -iname \*.css ! -iname  "*_bkp*" ! -iname  "*_backup" \) -newermt 2022-12-27 -print0 | xargs -0 zip -r /UpdatedFiles.zip
```

but it is not excluding files that have character '_bkp' or '_backup' in their file names.

please help me to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1447690/968501

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue, did some modifications in command and it worked for me -

Here is the workable command  -

```
find /httpdocs/ -type f \( -iname \*.php -o -iname \*.html -o -iname \*.js -o -iname \*.css \) ! \( -name "*bkp*" -o -name "*backup*" \) -newermt 2022-12-27 -print0 | xargs -0 zip -r /UpdatedFiles.zip
```